plantuml use mindmap-style arrows in other diagrams
I would like to use mindmap style arrows in non-mindmap diagrams.
example:
@startuml
left to right direction

object o1
object o2
object o3

o1 --> o2
o1 --> o3
@enduml

gives me:

Which works.
But I like the arrow style from the mindmap better:
@startmindmap
* O1
** O2
** O3
@endmindmap

Which gives me:

So, the arrows to the sub-components start from the same position, then branch out, and are curved.
I can't seem to find in the documentation how I can choose this arrow style. Is it even possible?

The closest I have seen is Grouping inheritance arrow heads on the class diagram.


Not exactly what I desire, but already a major improvement in some of my diagrams. I upvoted, but did not accept the answer (since it is not exactly what I desire). Thanks for making this suggestion; perhaps I will never accept an answer if it is simply not possible
